# css exclamation at the start

Tags: css

In a project which I am working on, I have encountered various css rules where the exclamation mark is at the start of the rule. What does the exclamation mark at the start do?

```
.uploadResume input[type="text"],
.uploadResume input[type="file"] {
    display: inline-block;
    !width: 24%;
    background: transparent!important;
}

.uploadCover {
    !margin-left: -22px;
}
```

Comment: Presumably a means to disable the rule.

Comment: I think @Utkanos is correct. It seems like a hacky way to disable a rule by making it invalid forcing browsers to not apply it.

Comment: Using that exclamation mark or any other symbols or letters would make a style property invalid. So either you use `!margin : ` or `#margin` or `maargin`, you would have the same outcome. It isn't an 'official' rule or practice and it just results in invalid CSS. Which is wrong. And frankly, i can't seem to figure out why would someone use that. If you don't want to use a style but in the same time you don't want to delete it, comment it out. `/* style */`

Comment: @MihaiT IKR, Thats what I too was thinking, like IDEs already take care of the commenting part you just have to press one combination of a hotkey.